# htaccess rewrite country without subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, rewrite, rewritecond

i need to rewrite URL from

```
us.example.com
```

to

```
example.com?country=us
```

without subdomains

I tried these 2 rules:

1.

```
RewriteRule (US|EG) ?c=$1 [NC , L]
```

2.

```
RewriteRule :\/\/(.*?).example.com ?C=$1 [NC , L]
```

but they didn't work.

so .. is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do your subdomains point to the same area of the filesystem as the main domain?

Comment: ...And what do you want to do with the URL-path? Anything? What is the actual _file_ you are redirecting to? (`example.com?country=us` isn't strictly valid.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "rewrite" a URL across different hostnames (you would need to implement a reverse proxy) and I assume a "redirect" is undesirable.

However, if the subdomains and main domain all point to the same area of the filesystem then you don't need to change the hostname/domain. A ordinary rewrite (on the same host) is all that's required.

To check the subdomain on the requested host, you need a condition (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable (ie. the value of the `Host` HTTP request header). The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path part of the URL only.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^country=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(us|eg)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?country=%1 [L]
```

As noted above, this assumes the subdomains and main domain point to the same area of the filesystem. This is common on a system where all requests are managed by a single CMS. (And you aren't making any attempt to change the hostname in your example directives.)

The `%1` backreference holds the subdomain ("us" or "eg" in this example) from the requested hostname.

The additional condition that checks the query string for the absence of the `country=` URL parameter is to prevent a rewrite loop.

However, you've not stated anything about the URL-path? And you should be rewriting directly to the file that is handling the request (`index.php`?). In its current state, the above "rewrite" is reliant on mod_dir making an additional subrequest for the DirectoryIndex.

---

> 1. `RewriteRule (US|EG) ?c=$1 [NC , L]`
> 2. `RewriteRule :\/\/(.*?).example.com ?C=$1 [NC , L]`

There are numerous errors with these directives:

- You say you've tried these, however, the erroneous *spaces* in the *flags* argument will result in an immediate 500 Internal Server Error when the file is first parsed.
- As mentioned above, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) matches against the URL-path only. This does not include the hostname.
- The regex in #1 is far too general and matches "US" or "EG" *anywhere*.
- In order to match against an absolute URL (as you appear to be trying to do in the second example) then you would need to match against `THE_REQUEST` server variable (which contains the first line of the request headers, include the request *method*).